# Refresh PyGTK window every minute?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

I have a `PyGTK` app that is supposed to be a desktop monitor of some data source. I have it almost complete but there is just this one problem of auto-refreshing.

In my program I want it to fetch data from database and refresh the window every minute. Here's what I have for the refresh function (it refresh once per second now for testing):

```
def refresh(self):
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=IL1WP0550DB;Database=Customer_Analytics;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TestGroup_test_group_result")

        data = []
        while 1:
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if not row:
                break
            #data.append([row.TestGroupName, row.PWF, row.Expires, row.TestGroupID])
            data.append([str(datetime.now()), row.PWF, row.Expires, row.TestGroupID])

        cnxn.close()
        self.fill_text(data)

        threading.Timer(1, self.refresh).start()
```

Using this function I can update my window, but it only works when I drag my window around. When I put a series of `print` statements around, it looks like it is only executing the script when the window is moving.

Anyone know how to fix it?

---

Additional info: I realize that it only processes the refresh when there is a signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GTK you need to make sure your widgets are only updated from the main thread. You can do this by using a timeout function with `gtk.timeout_add()` or `gtk.timeout_add_seconds()`. If you use python's threading functions the widgets are not updated from the main thread and so it does not work. For timeouts of greater than one second you should use `gtk.timeout_add_seconds()` as it avoids unnecessary wake ups where the timing isn't that critical.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gtk.timeout_add(1000, self.refresh)` instead of `threading.Timer(1, self.refresh).start()` did the trick :)
Don't know why though

Comment: With GTK you need to make sure your widgets are only updated from the main thread which is why adding a timeout function works but using pitons threading functions does not. For timeouts of greater than one second you should use gtk.timeout_add_seconds as it avoids unnecessary wake ups where the timing isn't that critical.

Comment: Thanks @PhillipWood, can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

python3:

```
from gi.repository import GObject

def refresh_data(self):
    [do stuff here]
    if self.running:
        GObject.timeout_add(1000, self.refresh_data)
```

Set self.running to False to stop.